# Editing the content of git repository without `git clone`

Tags: git, clone, git-remote

I want to update a remote rep by adding more content but am wondering if I can do that without having to clone all its content first.

Is it possible to establish the same kind of connection between the folder on my machine and an existing remote rep without downloading the remote content?

Comment: I’m thinking you might want a shallow clone?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Git is a distributed source code repository.  You work with a complete copy of the remote repository, then push changes after you've resolved the merge collisions, if there are any.  I suspect you don't want to clone a rather large git repository.

Comment: Dang it. Thanks for the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Note that my suggestion involves an external system called Gerrit (code review web system) but Gerrit has such a feature:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-inline-edit.html